# mysql query child parent relation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT bs.i_description,col.Column_name,bs.Tm_id,ad.UserName as name,
        a.fk_sprint_id as spid,b.fk_back_id,b.u_pos_is,b.s_id,b.color,b._left,b._top,
        b.wiptime as wiptime,b.dodtime as dodtime,b.Dep_status 
FROM backToSprint a 
JOIN backToSprint b ON a.`s_id` = b.`fk_f_id` 
join backlog bs on bs.b_id=b.fk_back_id 
left join admin ad on bs.Tm_id=ad.adminID 
left join admin_column col on col.column_id=b.u_pos_is
where a.fk_sprint_id=3 and a.teamid=1 
ORDER BY a.`fk_f_id`
```

Where I got output like

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [i_description] => Story 1
        [Column_name] => Backlogs
        [Tm_id] => 0
        [name] => 
        [spid] => 3
        [fk_back_id] => 408
        [u_pos_is] => 1
        [s_id] => 5
        [color] => 2
        [_left] => 18
        [_top] => -9
        [wiptime] => 
        [dodtime] => 
        [Dep_status] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [i_description] => Story 2
        [Column_name] => Backlogs
        [Tm_id] => 0
        [name] => 
        [spid] => 3
        [fk_back_id] => 409
        [u_pos_is] => 1
        [s_id] => 6
        [color] => 3
        [_left] => 18
        [_top] => -9
        [wiptime] => 
        [dodtime] => 
        [Dep_status] => 0
    )

)
```

Here Column name is same so I expect output like

```
Array
(
  ['c'] => Array
    (
            [Column_name] => Backlogs
    )
 [0] => Array
    (
        [i_description] => Story 1
        [Column_name] => Backlogs
        [Tm_id] => 0
        [name] => 
        [spid] => 3
        [fk_back_id] => 408
        [u_pos_is] => 1
        [s_id] => 5
        [color] => 2
        [_left] => 18
        [_top] => -9
        [wiptime] => 
        [dodtime] => 
        [Dep_status] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [i_description] => Story 2
        [Column_name] => Backlogs
        [Tm_id] => 0
        [name] => 
        [spid] => 3
        [fk_back_id] => 409
        [u_pos_is] => 1
        [s_id] => 6
        [color] => 3
        [_left] => 18
        [_top] => -9
        [wiptime] => 
        [dodtime] => 
        [Dep_status] => 0
    )

)
```

Then i tried

```
$this->view->getstories['c'] = ['Column_name' => array_unique(array_column(  $this->view->getstories, 'Column_name'))];
```

which didn't get actual output.i got output like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [i_description] => Story 1
            [Column_name] => Backlogs
            [Tm_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [spid] => 3
            [fk_back_id] => 408
            [u_pos_is] => 1
            [s_id] => 5
            [color] => 2
            [_left] => 18
            [_top] => -9
            [wiptime] => 
            [dodtime] => 
            [Dep_status] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [i_description] => Story 2
            [Column_name] => WIP
            [Tm_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [spid] => 3
            [fk_back_id] => 409
            [u_pos_is] => 2
            [s_id] => 6
            [color] => 3
            [_left] => 18
            [_top] => -9
            [wiptime] => 
            [dodtime] => 
            [Dep_status] => 0
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [Column_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Backlogs
                    [1] => WIP
                )

        )

)
```

(Here i have another column name WIP)
But i want a nested array like

```
Array
    (




        [c1] => Array
            (
                [Column_name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Backlogs

                    )
[0] => Array
            (
                [i_description] => Story 1
                [Column_name] => Backlogs
                [Tm_id] => 0
                [name] => 
                [spid] => 3
                [fk_back_id] => 408
                [u_pos_is] => 1
                [s_id] => 5
                [color] => 2
                [_left] => 18
                [_top] => -9
                [wiptime] => 
                [dodtime] => 
                [Dep_status] => 0
            )
    [c2] => Array
            (
                [Column_name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => WIP

                    )
[0] => Array
            (
             [i_description] => Story 2
            [Column_name] => WIP
            [Tm_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [spid] => 3
            [fk_back_id] => 409
            [u_pos_is] => 2
            [s_id] => 6
            [color] => 3
            [_left] => 18
            [_top] => -9
            [wiptime] => 
            [dodtime] => 
            [Dep_status] => 0
            )

            )

    )
```

Please help me to solve this issue
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect such a result? Is there any more code involved?

Comment: to get that kind of output you have to do modification in `while()` loop data fetching code. You can't get that at your query end. Show us the php code. Also once check the expected output , i think  all data needs to be inside `c` array? Also what is `c` BY the way?from where it came?

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for the reply..I want to lis it like column name as mainheading then story1 story 2

Comment: @AlivetoDie thanks for the reply..is it possible using mysql only? please help me

Comment: @shythyamenon  i don't think so. because array creation is part of `PHP` not `MySQL`

Comment: @AlivetoDie can you please show me one example?

Comment: @shythyamenon  as i said show me the php code. I will rectify that. otherwise it seems that you are telling `please do code for me`.

Comment: It's not generally a good idea to mix string and numeric keys in the same array.

Comment: What should the value of `$result['c']['Column_name']` be if there's more than one `Column_Name` value in your results?

Comment: @Barmar sorry..i have more than one column name

Comment: So what should the result look like if they aren't all `Backlogs`?

Comment: @Barmar suppose there are two different column  names like backlog and WIP result should be like array[2] where WIP as column name

Comment: @Barmar please help me

Comment: What does extracting the `Column_name` values have to do with the parent-child relationship in your question title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is nested arrays. Do it while fetching the rows from the query, using `$row['Column_name']` as the key of the main array, and pushing each row onto that nested array.

```
$results = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $results[$row['Column_name']][] = $row;
}
```

This will create a result like:

```
Array
(
    [Backlogs] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [i_description] => Story 1
            [Column_name] => Backlogs
            [Tm_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [spid] => 3
            [fk_back_id] => 408
            [u_pos_is] => 1
            [s_id] => 5
            [color] => 2
            [_left] => 18
            [_top] => -9
            [wiptime] => 
            [dodtime] => 
            [Dep_status] => 0
        )
    )
    [WIP] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [i_description] => Story 2
            [Column_name] => WIP
            [Tm_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [spid] => 3
            [fk_back_id] => 409
            [u_pos_is] => 2
            [s_id] => 6
            [color] => 3
            [_left] => 18
            [_top] => -9
            [wiptime] => 
            [dodtime] => 
            [Dep_status] => 0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

There's no need for the `c1` and `c2` keys, just use the `Column_name` values as the keys of the main array.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer.but ihave one doubt now the array like [c] => Array
        (
            [Column_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => WIP    then its stories?then  [c] => Array
        (
            [Column_name] => Array
                (
                   
                    [1] => Backlogs hen its stories?

Comment: first parent as backlogs and then its stories.second as WIP then its stories..like so?

Comment: You can't have two `c` keys in the same array.

Comment: Maybe you want nested arrays, like `["Backlog" => [ all the backlog rows ], "WIP" => [ all the WIP rows]]`?

Comment: Edit the question to show what you really want, and I'll update the answer.